# How does one get div content line-by-line with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to process the content of a `<div>` line-by-line. A *shortened* piece of it looks like this:

```
<div id='aoeu'>
    Ammonium NH%4^+ <br />
    Copper(I) Cu^+ <br />
    Gold(I) Au^+ <br />
    Rubidium Rb^+ <br />
    Acetone CH%3COCH%3 <br />
    Glycerin C%3H%5(OH)%3 <br />
</div>
```

I need to work with each line individually with Javascript.

Comment: Are the "lines" separated by newline characters (`\n`)? Because if you want them to actually appear on separate lines in the browser you need to put `<br>` between.

Comment: Ah yes, nice catch. I'll get on that...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that the "lines" are separated by newline characters you can do something like this:

```
​var el = document.get​ElementById("aoeu"),
    content = el.innerHTML.replace(/  |^\s+|\s+$/g,""),
    lines = content.split("\n");
```

That is, get the `innerHTML` of the element, remove the leading and trailing whitespace, and then split on the newline character.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RG2WT/

EDIT: Now that you've added `<br>` elements (though I'd remove the trailing one):

```
var el = document.getElementById("aoeu"),
    content = el.innerHTML.replace(/^\s+|\s*(<br *\/?>)?\s*$/g,""),
    lines = content.split(/\s*<br ?\/?>\s*/);
```

That is, get the `innerHTML`, remove leading and traling whitespace and any trailing `<br>` element, and then split on each remaining `<br>` element plus the whitespace around it.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RG2WT/3/

Either way `lines` will be an array with each element being one of your lines. Either way I'm removing leading and trailing white space so that, e.g., the first item will be `"Ammonium NH%4^+"` not `"    Ammonium NH%4^+ "`.

Comment: Why are you using a comma as a line terminator?

Comment: @ChristianMann - I'm not. I'm splitting on a newline character.

Comment: `document.getElementById("aoeu"),` Why is there a comma there and not a semicolon?

Comment: @ChristianMann - Because the `var` statement goes for three lines and declares three variables, each separated by a comma.

Comment: I actually ended up using the version of your code before you made it compatible with `<br />`, but it worked like a charm. Thank you to the Awnry Bear too, as his code also works.

Answer (score 1):

I would first get the innerHTML and assign to a var. Take the var and split on br's to get an array, which you can do whatever you need with.

```
var contents = document.getElementById("aoeu").innerHTML;
var lines = contents.split("<br />");
// Do whatever you want with lines
```