# Is there a way to extract single lines from a `<div>`-Element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hyphenation

Look at this `<div>`-Element:

```
<div id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque pena&shy;tibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</div>
```

and this css:

```
div#text {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

When this div is rendered, it is split into many lines and might look like this block:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
>   consectetuer adipiscing elit.
>   Aenean commodo ligula
>   eget dolor. Aenean massa.
>   Cum sociis natoque pena-
>   tibus et magnis dis
>   parturient montes, nascetur
>   ridiculus mus.

Is there a way to extract, let's say, the 6th line of this div's content using Javascript? This means, I want a function, to which I pass the value `3` and then it returns »tibus et magnis dis«. Is this possible? If so, how can this be done?

Whatch the soft hyphen (`&shy;`) in the word »penatibus« that makes the word be splittet into two parts.

In a similar way, think of the css-property `hyphen`:

```
div#text {
    hyphens: auto;
}
```

This causes the rendering-machine to hyphenate the text without the need of inserting dashes or `&shy;`-entities.

Remember, that there is no newline or `<br>` or any other marker in the text that splits the text into lines. It is just the rendering-machines word-wrap-algorithm together with css-styles and the textstring itself that is responsible for which words are written into which line.

This is also the reason why this question is different form [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572506/how-does-one-get-div-content-line-by-line-with-javascript).

This Question is also different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16223213/how-to-capture-one-line-of-text-in-a-div) because the solutions posted there ignore the influence of hyphenations.

Also think of ligatures (like f followed by i in many fonts is replaced by a new glyph, fi, that is a little bit shorter than a normal f followed by a normal i would be. This may influence word-wrap and hyphenation. But when you put each character of your text into a `<span>`-element to be able to read the position of all these elements, then you will not see f and i being replaced by its shorter ligature fi, and so this method does not return correct results in all cases.

Comment: I am almost 100% certain this is not going to be possible.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @MelanciaUK: My question is similar to the one you linked to, but there the influence of hyphens is ignored in all answeres. I edited my question to make clear, that this is also an important fact that needs to be dealt with in an answer.

Comment: @CharlieWynn: I need to know where exactly the rendering machine makes the line-breaakes, because I encountered a case where the browser rendered a newly inserted text into 3 lines, and some miliseconds later it changed it into 2 lines. To bad that my script measured the hight of that div just inbetween, and so got wrong results. Look here fore details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30016844/javascript-too-fast-for-dom-manipulation

Comment: Can you use one of the answers in the other post and add a check to see if the last character in the line is a hyphen? If it is, simply grab all characters before the next blank space.

Comment: You say the problem is created because your script performs an action before a browser optimization is complete... how about just having your script run with a short delay - `setTimeout(function() {[your code here]}, 100)`  (or however long it needs...) - and see if you can simply avoid the problem altogether?

Comment: @GuyPassy: Maybe you should write this answer to the question to which it belongs, which is not this question here.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Dude... you wrote "The problem is, that the browser (Safari or Chrome on OS X) render a certain newly inserted text into 3 Lines (giving a hight of 60px), and some miliseconds later improved rendering [...]". I'm suggesting you wait for the render to complete.

Comment: @GuyPassy: Yes, it is true that I wrote this. But I also wrote, that this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30016844/javascript-too-fast-for-dom-manipulation contains the question that deals with that milisecond-rerendering-problem. Here we talk about extracting lines from a div. Your answer does not address the line-extracting problem, so it makes no sense to post it here. Your answer addresses the milisecond-rerendering-problem, so you should post it there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30016844/javascript-too-fast-for-dom-manipulation

Comment: @HubertSchölnast *sheepishly* oh I see

Comment: I don't see how this got closed as a duplicate for the mentioned post. It simply isn't or did those floggers never read through both questions?

Comment: @Icepickle: I nominated the Question for reopening. Please klick on "reopen" just below the ende of my question.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast alas, I need 3k to make this happen ;)

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could trick a bit, and copy the width of the existing element, and then add word per word to see if the height of the new element changes, then increase the line.

I wrote a basic version of this. This only takes into account the width of the div element, none of the other styles (like font-size, letter-spacing, ... for that, you could copy the css styles from the element you wish to get the line nr from)

```js
function copyStyle(source, target) {
  var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(source, null),
    prop, obj = computedStyle, i, len, style = '';
  for (i = 0, len = computedStyle.length; i < len; i++) {
      prop = computedStyle[i];
      style += prop + ': ' + obj[prop] + ';';
  }
  target.style = style;
}

function extractHyphens(array) {
  var word, i, len, shyElement = document.createElement('span');
  shyElement.innerHTML = '&shy;';
  for (i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
    word = array[i];
    if (word.indexOf(shyElement.innerHTML) >= 0) {
      word = word.split(shyElement.innerHTML);
      array.slice(i, 1, word);
    }
  }
}

function getLine(element, lineNr, callback, measuredWidth) {
  var hiddenElement,
    sourceElement = document.getElementById(element),
      textarea = document.getElementById('textarea'),
    lastHeight,
    outline = '',
    curline = -1,
    words, word;

  if (typeof measuredWidth === 'undefined' ||
    measuredWidth !== sourceElement.offsetWidth) {
    measuredWidth = sourceElement.offsetWidth;
    setTimeout(function() {
      getLine(element, lineNr, callback, measuredWidth);
    }, 100);
  } else {
    hiddenElement = document.createElement('div');
    words = sourceElement.innerHTML;
    words = words.split(' ');
    extractHyphens(words);
    copyStyle(sourceElement, hiddenElement);
    hiddenElement.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    // we don't want anything affecting the height of the "hidden" element
    hiddenElement.style.height = 'auto';
    delete hiddenElement.style['minHeight'];
    delete hiddenElement.style['maxHeight'];
    document.body.appendChild(hiddenElement);
    lastHeight = hiddenElement.offsetHeight;
    for (var i = 0, len = words.length; i < len; i++) {
      word = words[i];
      hiddenElement.innerHTML += word;
      if (lastHeight !== hiddenElement.offsetHeight) {
        curline++;
      }
      if (lineNr === curline) {
        outline += word + ' ';
      }
      hiddenElement.innerHTML += ' ';
      lastHeight = hiddenElement.offsetHeight;
      if (curline > lineNr) {
        break;
      }
    }
    document.body.removeChild(hiddenElement);
    setTimeout(function() {
      callback(element, outline);
    }, 0);
  }
}

function showResult(element, result) {
  alert(element + ': ' + result);
}

window.onload = function() {
  getLine('test', 1, showResult);
  getLine('test2', 6, showResult);
};
```

```css
#test2 {
  width: 50px;
  font-size: 7px;
  padding: 3px;
}
div {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque&shy;&raquo;penatibus&laquo; et magnis dis parturient montes, ascetur ridiculus mus.</div>
<div id="test2">lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, ascetur ridiculus mus.</div>
```

Comment: good idea, but too slow. The problem is, that the browser (Safari or Chrome on OS X) render a certain newly inserted text into 3 Lines (giving a hight of 60px), and some miliseconds later improved rendering, and suddenly the same text fitted into 2 lines (40px high). The Problem is, that my script measures the elements hight before the final rendering-optimozation-step, and works with the hight of 60px that the user never sees, because it will be changed so quickly to 40px. AND: How does your solution deal with soft hyphens (`&shy;`)?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Could you then give a more appropriate test that could check why the current exercise is to slow? I can give an attempted solution for the resizing of the element, that would then restart once the height would be stable, however, I do not have OS X so it's hard to test for me). I updated the script a little to use a callback when the result was found (or not found), i tried around a bit with the &shy; but since it's a rendered text it's not easy to get it separated (and in the end, doesn't affect the rendering how i thought it would).